# kinetic source install on Fedora23

Tags: ros, source, ros-kinetic, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

Where trying to install kinetic from source on Fedora23 I have this error :

```
CMake Warning at /home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/shiboken_helper.cmake:18 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindShiboken2.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Shiboken2", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Shiboken2" with
  any of the following names:

    Shiboken2Config.cmake
    shiboken2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Shiboken2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Shiboken2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Shiboken2" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/CMakeLists.txt:41 (include)


CMake Warning at /home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/shiboken_helper.cmake:23 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPySide2.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PySide2", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PySide2" with any
  of the following names:

    PySide2Config.cmake
    pyside2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PySide2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "PySide2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "PySide2" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/CMakeLists.txt:41 (include)


CMake Warning at /home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/shiboken_helper.cmake:34 (message):
  Shiboken binding generator NOT available.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/qt_gui_cpp_shiboken/CMakeLists.txt:41 (include)


-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found suitable version "2.7.11", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- SIP binding generator available.
-- Python binding generators: sip
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp
==> make -j8 -l8 in '/home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
[ 83%] Built target qt_gui_cpp
[ 88%] Running SIP generator for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 47, in <module>
    config = Configuration()
  File "/home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 16, in __init__
    ['qmake', '-query'], env=env, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/build.make:89: receptet för målet ”sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile” misslyckades
make[2]: *** [sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Fel 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:374: receptet för målet ”src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all” misslyckades
make[1]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all] Fel 2
Makefile:138: receptet för målet ”all” misslyckades
make: *** [all] Fel 2
<== Failed to process package 'qt_gui_cpp': 
  Command '['/home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/install_isolated/env.sh', 'make', '-j8', '-l8']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp && /home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_kinetic/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8

Command failed, exiting.
```

Where apparently I miss Shibuken2 and PySide2. I have installed  those packages :

```
pyside-tools.x86_64                               0.2.13-9.fc23                       @fedora 
python-pyside.x86_64                              1.2.2-4.fc23                        @fedora 
python-pyside-devel.x86_64                        1.2.2-4.fc23                        @fedora
```

And during the dependency resolve I only had the gazebo dependy pointed at :

```
[malcolm@PC124-180 source_kinetic]$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
gazebo_ros: No definition of [libgazebo7-dev] for OS [fedora]
gazebo_plugins: No definition of [libgazebo7-dev] for OS [fedora]
```

So I guess those missing packages should be added to the list of dependencies ?

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236420/kinetic-source-install-on-fedora23/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a partial answer, you need to get PySide through the package manager:

`sudo dnf install pyside-tools python-pyside python-pyside-devel python2-pyudev-pyside`

See the full list of what I had to install here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/238007/avcodech-no-such-file-fedora-24

---

Originally posted by [BrannonKing](https://answers.ros.org/users/27276/brannonking/) with karma: 76 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0